# Can GoogleSheet write json to local folder in computer automatically by apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to write json files to the local computer( D://MyJsons ) by apps script.
(I've already wrote the code to get json string. I just need a way to write to the local folder)
I've found DriveApp.createFile to write to google drive, but not found a way to save in the local computer.
Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Google Apps Script is not able to access local storage devices. You might use client side code. Spend some time learning about creating custom dialogs / sidebars using the HtmlService (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs).  If you need further help,  show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script only work in the cloud, it has no access to your local storage. The best way to do it would probably to setup a synced folder between your computer / server and your drive.

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking about changing excel to google Sheets as my game data editor. It seems not efficient if I can't save JSON to local.